# AWS Encryption SDK Header Mismatch between Regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, encryption-symmetric, amazon-kms, aws-regions

I'm using the [Amazon Encryption SDK](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-encryption-sdk-java) to encrypt data before storing it in a database. I'm also using [Amazon KMS](https://aws.amazon.com/kms/). As part of the encryption process, the SDK stores the *Key Provider ID* of the data key used to encrypt in the generated cipher-text header.

As described in the documentation here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/message-format.html#header-structure

> The encryption operations in the AWS Encryption SDK return a single
>   data structure or message that contains the encrypted data
>   (ciphertext) and all encrypted data keys. To understand this data
>   structure, or to build libraries that read and write it, you need to
>   understand the message format.
>
> The message format consists of at least two parts: a header and a
>   body. In some cases, the message format consists of a third part, a
>   footer.

The Key Provider ID value contains the Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of the AWS KMS customer master key (CMK).

Here is where the issue comes in. Right now I have two different KMS regions available for encryption. Each Key Provider ID has the exact same Encrypted Data Key value. So either key could be used to decrypt the data. However, the issue is with the ciphertext headers. Let's say I have KMS1 and KMS2. If I encrypt the data with the key provided by KMS1, then the Key Provider ID will be stored in the ciphertext header. If I attempt to decrypt the data with KMS2, even though the Encrypted Data Key is the same, the decryption will fail because the header does not contain the Key Provider for KMS2. It has the Key Provider ID for KMS1. It fails with this error:

```
com.amazonaws.encryptionsdk.exception.BadCiphertextException: Header integrity check failed.
        at com.amazonaws.encryptionsdk.internal.DecryptionHandler.verifyHeaderIntegrity(DecryptionHandler.java:312) ~[application.jar:na]
        at com.amazonaws.encryptionsdk.internal.DecryptionHandler.readHeaderFields(DecryptionHandler.java:389) ~[application.jar:na]
 ...
com.amazonaws.encryptionsdk.internal.DecryptionHandler.verifyHeaderIntegrity(DecryptionHandler.java:310) ~[application.jar:na]
        ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!
```

It fails to verify the header integrity and fails. This is not good, because I was planning to have multiple KMS's in case of one region KMS failing. We duplicate our data across all our regions, and we thought that we could use any KMS from the regions to decrypt as long as the encrypted data keys match. However, it looks like I'm locked into using only the original KMS that was encrypting the data? How on earth can we scale this to multiple regions if we can only rely on a single KMS?

I could include all the region master keys in the call to encrypt the data. That way, the headers would always match, although it would not reflect which KMS it's actually using. However, that's also not scalable, since we could add/remove regions in the future, and that would cause issues with all the data that's already encrypted.

Am I missing something? I've thought about this, and I want to solve this problem without crippling any integrity checks provided by the SDK/Encryption.

Update:

Based on a comment from @jarmod

Using an alias doesn't work either because we can only associate an alias to a key in the region, and it stores the resolved name of the key ARN it's pointing to anyway.

I'm reading [this document and it says](https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/aws-kms-best-practices.pdf)

> Additionally, envelope encryption can help to design your application
>   for disaster recovery. You can move your encrypted data as-is between
>   Regions and only have to reencrypt the data keys with the
>   Region-specific CMKs

However, that's not accurate at all, because the encryption SDK will fail to decrypt on a different region because the Key Provider ID of the re-encrypted data keys will be totally different!

Comment: I'm not sure this solves your problem but read the section on Key Aliases at https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/aws-kms-best-practices.pdf.

Comment: @jarmod That's a great suggestion! Will definitely check that out, thanks.

Comment: @jarmod Tried it, but the sdk stores the resolved key id from the alias during the encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies since I'm not familiar with Java programming, but I believe there is confusion how you are using the KMS CMKs to encrypt (or decrypt) the data using keys from more than one-region for DR.

When you use multiple master keys to encrypt plaintext, any one of the master keys can be used to decrypt the plaintext. Note that, only one master key (let's say MKey1) generates the plaintext data key which is used to encrypt the data. This plaintext data key is then encrypted by the other master key (MKey2) as well.

As a result, you will have encrypted data + encrypted data key (using MKey1) + encrypted data key (using MKey2).

If for some reason MKey1 is unavailable and you want to decrypt the ciphertext, SDK can be used to decrypt the encrypted data key using MKey2, which can decrypt the ciphertext.

So, yes, you have to specify multiple KMS CMK ARN in your program if you want to use multiple KMS. The document shared by you has an [example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/java-example-code.html#java-example-multiple-providers) as well which I'm sure you are aware of.

Comment: If I encrypt one plaintext block with master keys k1 and k2, they have to be decrypted with a provider that has the same ordering - e.g. master keys k1 and k2, it will not work if it loads up master keys k2 and then k1. I suspect this was not intentional and the sdk just delegates the core work to java crypto internals, because it tries to compare byte for byte.

Comment: Here's my test:

I encrypted a message with providers k1 and k2, the resulting ciphertext headers start with
aws-crypto-public-key...aws-kmsKarn:aws:kms:us-east-......aws-kmsKarn:aws:kms:us-west-...

I encrypted a message with providers k2 and k1, the resulting ciphertext headers start with
aws-crypto-public-key...aws-kmsKarn:aws:kms:us-west-......aws-kmsKarn:aws:kms:us-east-...
I am not able to decrypt message 2 with key providers in order k1 and k2, only providers in order k2 and k1. This makes me assume that even specifying all the providers is inflexible for future region changes